# No results being brought back

Tags: php, html, sql, forms, no-response

Im desperate once again. I am trying to create a search page which brings back the following results

```
$brandName = filter_has_var(INPUT_GET, 'brandName') ? $_GET['brandName']: null;
$shoeSize= filter_has_var(INPUT_GET, 'shoeSize') ? $_GET['shoeSize']: null;
$colour = filter_has_var(INPUT_GET, 'colour') ? $_GET['colour']: null;
```

But when i submit the web form it does not retrieve any records.
can anybody please tell me where I am going wrong.

Below is the code I have done so far

```
<body>
     <table>
     <tr>
     <th>Brand</th>
     <th>Name</th>
     <th>Size</th>
     <th>Colour</th>
     <th>Gender</th>
     <th>Price</th>
     <th>Description</th>
     </tr>
<?php
include 'database_mysqli_conn.php';

$brandName = filter_has_var(INPUT_GET, 'brandName') ? $_GET['brandName']: null;
$shoeSize= filter_has_var(INPUT_GET, 'shoeSize') ? $_GET['shoeSize']: null;
$colour = filter_has_var(INPUT_GET, 'colour') ? $_GET['colour']: null;


$sql = "SELECT * FROM sh_brand b inner join sh_shoe s on b.brandID = s.brandID WHERE 1"; // use WHERE to implement the form to pull certain types of data

if (!empty($brandName)) {

    $sql= $sql." AND brandName = '$brandName'";

    }

if (!empty($shoeSize)) {

    $sql= $sql." AND shoeSize = '$shoeSize'";

}

if (!empty($colour)) {

    $sql= $sql." AND colour = '$colour'";

}

$stmt = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($stmt)) {
        $brandName = $row['brandName'];
    $shoeName = $row['shoeName'];
    $shoeSize = $row['shoeSize'];
    $colour = $row['colour'];
    $gender = $row['gender'];
        $price = $row['price'];
    $description = $row['description'];

    echo "<tr>
        <td>$brandName</td>
        <td>$shoeName</td>
        <td>$shoeSize</td>
        <td>$colour</td>
        <td>$gender</td>
                <td>$price</td>
                <td>$description</td>
    </tr>";

}


mysqli_free_result($stmt);
mysqli_close($conn);

?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

WEB FORM------------

```
<body>
<form id ="SearchPage" action="SearchShoes.php" method="get">
<h1>Search Page</h1>

    Brand <input type="text" name="brandName" />

    Shoe Size <input type="text" name="shoeSize" />

    Colour <select name="colour">
                <option value = "greenn">Green</option>
                <option value = "white">White</option>
                <option value = "grey">Grey</option>
                <option value = "black">Black</option>
                <option value = "brown">Bronw</option>
                <option value = "white/red">White/Red</option>  
            </select>


        <input type ="submit" value-"Find shoes"/>
```

Comment: What's not working about it? Have you tried running the generated SQL using your local friendly MySQL client?

Comment: Yes i have ran the sql query in phpmyadmin and it work correctly, but once i enter the search for the shoe I am looking for it brings back an empty Table outline with just the table heading and no results :/

Comment: “when i submit the web form” probably means you **post** data to the handler, while you are then dealing with `_GET`.

Comment: Post your HTML form.

Comment: form id ="SearchPage" action="SearchShoes.php" method="get" -- this is what i have used in the html form

Comment: Post your entire form in your question, not in comments. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: ah ok sorry i will do

Comment: how do i post it in the question? I'm new to this sorry

Comment: Go back to your question and click on edit at the bottom.

Comment: Is `shoeSize` a string or integer in the database? You're wrapping it in quotes in your query. If you're running mySQL in strict mode this won't work.

Comment: Not an answer, but your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should be using bound parameters. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/3794472

Comment: Your value for the color green looks wrong   greenn